# org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException while upgrading Neo4j 1.9.8 to 2.3.8

Tags: java, neo4j

Unexpected error : org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.assertInUnterminatedTransaction(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getTopLevelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getKernelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:113)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.get(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.LegacyIndexProxy.query(LegacyIndexProxy.java:363)
    at au.com.pwc.nodalgeography.graph.GraphNodeIterator.getNext(GraphNodeIterator.java:32)
    at au.com.pwc.nodalgeography.graph.GraphNodeIterator.getNext(GraphNodeIterator.java:14)
    at com.googlecode.totallylazy.iterators.StatefulIterator.hasNext(StatefulIterator.java:23)
    at com.googlecode.totallylazy.iterators.StatefulIterator.next(StatefulIterator.java:36)
    at com.googlecode.totallylazy.Computation$2.call(Computation.java:80)
    at com.googlecode.totallylazy.callables.LazyCallable.get(LazyCallable.java:19)
    at com.googlecode.totallylazy.Lazy.call(Lazy.java:22

```
protected Record getNext() throws Exception {  if (hits == null) {
        hits = index.query(query);
    }

    T next = hits.next();
    if (next == null) {
        return finished();
    } else {
        return nodeToRecord.call(next);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please detail your issue

Comment: I have upgraded neo4j embedded version from 1.9.8 to 2.3.8. I got above attached exception and also attached code snippet. appreciate your quick response

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you execute anything against the database you need to make sure you're inside the scope of a transaction. e.g.

```
try(Transaction tx = db.beginTransaction()) {    
  // do database work in this scope
}

// but no database work here
```

I think there might have been a change in the 2.0 series to require that you explicitly create those transactions, so that might be the issue you're seeing as a result of the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i have created transaction, but when i call db.beginTransaction() it is throwing nullPointerException. Also I'm suspecting on hits = index.query(query). because i could not able to print index.query(query) also